# Differences between using source and ./ a .sh file

Tags: make, source

I know the above topic has been discussed before

- `source` a .sh file and you retain the environmental variables after you are done with the sh file
- while `./` a .sh file and you lose the environmental variables after you are done

However, I have the following script, `makefile.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(pwd)

export PATH=$PATH:$PWD

## source the environment
source environment-setup
```

When I `source` the above file, it went through successfully even without exporting PATH. However when I use `./` of the above file, it gives me `./makefile.sh: 7: ./makefile.sh: source: not found`.

I have placed `environment-setup` in the same directory as the `makefile.sh`.  Do we need to do something more? Or am I missing out some subtle differences between `source` and `./

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of the shebang, `#!/bin/sh`, you are using `sh` and not `bash`.

`source` is a shell builtin for `bash` but not `sh` so for the script that you are sourcing, `source` doesn't exist in the environment which leads to the error when you execute the script with `./`

There are two ways that you can fix it:

1. Change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` assuming that `bash` is an available shell on your system and found in `/bin`.
2. Change the last line to

   ```
   . environment-setup
   ```

`.` has the same functionality as `source` in `sh` and also in `bash` and some of the other shells. It's best to use the absolute path to the `environment-source` file in case it isn't in the current working directory in which you are running the script so that it will work no matter what the cwd is at the time.

```
. /path/to/environment-setup
```

Comment: Hey it works perfectly

Comment: the correct second suggestion would be using posix `.` with an explicitly relative or absolute path. i.e. `. ./environment-setup`. `. environment-setup` wouldn't work if the current directory is not included in `PATH`.

Comment: More precisely, `source` is from csh, while `.` is from the Bourne shell. Some shells like bash and zsh support both though with variation in behaviour. You need `. ./environment-setup` if you want the `environment-setup` in the current working directory to be sourced and not the one in `$PATH` (with the behaviour varying whether the shell is in POSIX / sh mode or not in both bash and zsh).